# filter blogs by tags in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'd like to render a view in Django with objects that have certain tags.

Here's my model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    """Model representing a tag."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
    """Model representing a post."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ManyToManyField used because tag can contain many posts. Posts can cover many tags.
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags', blank=True, default='', help_text='Select a tag for this post')
```

after running migrations,
I see three tables generated in my DB:
`blog_tag`, `blog_post` and `blog_post_tag`
`blog_post` table doesn't contain a column called tag, instead, this `blog_post_tag` holds all the mapping.

What I'd like to achieve is to find all posts that have certain tags.

I tried to use `post_list = Post.objects.filter(tag__in=['AWS'])`, but this one throws

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'AWS'.
```

Any help on working this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you here filter on the *primary* key of the tag. If you want to filter on the `name`, you can filter with:

```
post_list = Post.objects.filter(tag__name__in=['AWS'])
```

Since the list here contains *one* element, you can filter with:

```
post_list = Post.objects.filter(tag__name='AWS')
```

Comment: It worked like a charm thanks for the education for Django newbies like me!